# Maybe monad in elisp

Tags: functional-programming, elisp, monads, emacs24

Here is my attempt to implement Maybe monad in elisp. It it function composition that breaks on first nil. However `value` is always `13`. Where is my error?

```
(defun .compose-maybe (&rest funcs)
  "Monad Maybe function composition with nil as Nothing."
  (lambda (arg)
    (if funcs
        (let ((value (funcall (apply #'.compose-maybe (cdr funcs)) arg)))
          (message "%s" value)
          (when value (funcall (car funcs) value))))
        arg))

(funcall (.compose-maybe (lambda (x) (* x 5)) (lambda (x) (+ 100 x))) 13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `arg` falls outside of the bouds of `(if funcs ...)`, thus the inner lambda in `.compose-maybe` always returns `arg` instead of only when `funcs` is `nil`.

```
(defun .compose-maybe (&rest funcs)
  "Monad Maybe function composition with nil as Nothing."
  (lambda (arg)
    (if funcs
        (let ((value (funcall (apply #'.compose-maybe (cdr funcs)) arg)))
          (message "%s" value)
          (when value (funcall (car funcs) value)))
      arg)))
```